# CreateProcessA() modifies seemingly unrelated constant integer

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to get an executable to copy itself to the Desktop and run the copy.
For this I am using CopyFile() and CreateProcessA(). While the code actually works, calling CreateProcessA() inside an if statement somehow modifies a constant integer that is part of the if condition, causing both the if and the else statement to execute. I don't really understand how this can happen. Here's the code

```
const int wtf {create_duplicate()};
if (wtf != 0) {
    std::cout << "Duplicate created" << std::endl;
    std::cout << wtf << " != 0 " << std::endl;
    STARTUPINFO info {sizeof(info)};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

    if (CreateProcessA(R"(C:\Users\maxlu\Desktop\test.exe)", "",
           nullptr, nullptr, true, 0,
           nullptr, nullptr, &info, &processInfo)) {
        WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    }
} else {
    std::cout << wtf << " == 0 " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Duplicate not created" << std::endl;
```

This is the output of the code:

```
Duplicate created
1 != 0
0 == 0
Duplicate not created
```

Comment: Can we have a [mcve]? Seems plausible that there is more needed to repro. Also, the second arg to `CreateProcessA` should be modifiable. You probably get lucky because of implementation details (internally your ANSI strings are converted to UTF-16 strings), and then `CreateProcessW` is called. But still.....

Comment: _I am trying to get an executable to copy itself to the Desktop and run the copy._ And, you are sure that the 2nd half of output isn't from _run the copy_? ;-)

Comment: I suspect `wtf` is in a quantum state evaluating to both `true` and `false` at the same time - or `Duplicate created` comes from the first instance of the program and `Duplicate not created` comes from the second instance.

Comment: Put a cout in the beginning of `int main()` to verify that your second output does not come from the second instance of your process.

Comment: I did not downvote however I think if the code context was improved this question could have a positive rating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely:

1. The program prints "Duplicate created" "1 != 0" because create_duplicate() succeeded.
2. The program runs another copy of itself.
3. In the second copy, create_duplicate() returns 0.
4. The second copy prints "0 == 0" "Duplicate not created."

The variable is not modified. Two copies of the program run, and each copy has its own variable.

Comment: I believe this all means it worked correctly. Otherwise you would have a situation where each process starts an additional process which starts an additional process ..

Comment: You are right, the second output is from the copy. What I actually wanted to achieve is the second copy being executed independent from the first process, so I didn't expect the output to show up in the same stdout.

Comment: Its a child process of the first.

Comment: I managed to achieve what I wanted by specifying the process creation flags CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP and DETACHED_PROCESS to the CreateProcessA() function